# Reports on the cases

Tags: reporting, case

[image]Whenever we create a new report on the case object by default 'Details' is hidden wherein I i create a report on any other object say account, contact, lead I don't need to check the 'Details'. Can this setting be changed on the case object? i.e by default the 'Details' should be checked?

[image]

Comment: screen shot would be helpful here

Comment: Does the edit helps?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no place to set default report parameters that can be used when creating a new report. You have to change whichever values you want every time you build a new report. I also don't see an Idea on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch), so perhaps you could create a new Idea.